# At least one output file must be specified, error message issue

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to export m3u8 which I assuming a streaming URL to mp4.

while googled the way, I couldn't found "https://gist.github.com/primaryobjects/7423d7982656a31e72542f60d30f9d30" this one that saying suggest to use ffmpeg.

so I installed ffmpeg and write down

https://gist.github.com/primaryobjects/7423d7982656a31e72542f60d30f9d30

on CMD but no luck with this code ;

`ffmpeg -user_agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/601.7.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.3 Safari/537.86.7" -i`
 http://221.157.125.242:1935/mp4/mp4/happyday/mp4:happyday190201_00W.mp4/playlist.m3u8
 -c copy pd.mkv

but it says:

> "At least one output file must be specified"

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Share full log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably missing double quotes around the -i parameter.
Try this way:

```
ffmpeg -user_agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/601.7.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.3 Safari/537.86.7" -i "http://221.157.125.242:1935/mp4/mp4/happyday/mp4:happyday190201_00W.mp4/playlist.m3u8" -c copy pd.mkv
```